# Android - Get data from server in every time

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, schedule

I wrote an item selling system using PHP and android.php app for sellers and android app for buyers.with android app buyers can order items from php server app.I used a slim rest API to do that.that part is ok.server app users can accept or deny buyer requests.
Now I need to get that response to android app.i used volley to send requests to server.how can I do that.
Need a code sample

Comment: you can find tutorial here https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Need to get realtime response

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like Firebase Cloud Messaging instead of regular polling to a REST API.

So when you receive message from Firebase, you can update the data accordingly.

You also may want to check Firebase Real-time database. Search for it in Google.

If you don't want to use Firebase, when response of API call comes to the app, wait for some time and make API call again.

Make a method to initiate an API call, and when you receive the response, update the UI and call that method again after some time using `Handler#postDelayed`

Comment: i want to do that without firebase

Comment: Then make REST api calls frequently. When result of one call comes, start new api call.

Comment: what is the best way to do that

Comment: can handler do that when app is not running

Comment: No, you can use background `Service`. But as I'm saying frequent polling to the server is very bad practice.